# MyPOS Checkout usingSymfony

Tags: symfony4

Actually im about to configure myPOS Checkout with my somfony 4 project but their documentation about the configuration not that clear have no idea from where to begin.
If anyone can help it would be a big favour.
Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the SDK - `composer require developermypos/mypos-checkout-sdk`
2. Include the SDK - `require_once './IPC/Loader.php';`.
3. Initialize it:
   `$cnf = new \Mypos\IPC\Config(); 
   $cnf->setIpcURL('https://mypos.eu/vmp/checkout-test/'); 
   $cnf->setLang('en'); 
   $cnf->setPrivateKeyPath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/keys/store_private_key.pem'); 
   $cnf->setAPIPublicKeyPath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/keys/api_public_key.pem'); 
   $cnf->setKeyIndex(1); 
   $cnf->setSid('000000000000010'); 
   $cnf->setVersion('1.3'); 
   $cnf->setWallet('61938166610');`
4. Use the test data available [here](https://developers.mypos.eu/en/doc/online_payments/v1_4/226-test-data)
5. Create a customer:
   `$customer = new \Mypos\IPC\Customer(); 
   $customer->setFirstName('John'); 
   $customer->setLastName('Smith'); 
   $customer->setEmail('demo@demo.demo'); 
   $customer->setPhone('+359111111111'); 
   $customer->setCountry('BGR'); 
   $customer->setAddress('Business Park Varna'); 
   $customer->setCity('Varna'); 
   $customer->setZip('9000');`
6. Create a cart object:
   `$cart = new \Mypos\IPC\Cart; 
   $cart->add('Some Book', 1, 9.99); //name, quantity, price 
   $cart->add('Some other book', 1, 4.56); 
   $cart->add('Discount', 1, -2.05);`
7. Initiate the purchase:
   `$purchase = new \Mypos\IPC\Purchase($cnf); 
   $purchase->setUrlCancel('https://example.com/ipc_cancel');
   $purchase->setUrlOk('https://example.com/ipc_ok');
   $purchase->setUrlNotify('https://example.com/ipc_notify');
   $purchase->setOrderID(uniqid()); //Some unique ID 
   $purchase->setCurrency('EUR'); 
   $purchase->setNote('Some note'); //Not required 
   $purchase->setCustomer($customer); 
   $purchase->setCart($cart);`

More info about the purchase method can be found [here](https://developers.mypos.eu/en/doc/online_payments/v1_4/147--api-call--ipcpurchase).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Answers that just provide a link and state to read it without explaining what's in them are generally frowned upon. It's much more helpful to summarise the relevant content from the link, and then provide the link if the user wants further information.

Comment: it doesn t help actually thats the documentation that i have and there s no clue in tehre

Comment: Do you have an online store (cart based) or do you want create a custom experience?

Comment: i have an online store but im not going through it i need to make a custom experience using PHP SDK

Comment: Eddited the answer

Comment: when i do that i get this error Compile Error: Symfony\Component\Debug\DebugClassLoader::main(): Failed opening required './IPC/Loader.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear')